# Help identify Native American Children's Book

Tags: identification-request

I used to have an illustrated picture book that was about a native american tale. Honestly it has been a long time, so the story is a bit fuzzy.

The art was spectacular, very colorful. Desert with  cliffs. Almost blob like sections of color as the rocks. Lots of heartlines in characters. (not Paul Goble style).

Story: It was about two brothers and maybe like a coming of age story. Like they ended up going into the desert alone and having to overcome monsters. One monster was an eagle and the brother sneaked into the nest to take something and then it was chasing after him and they were falling from a cliff. I think he ended up getting hurt. There might have been another monster and the boys might have split up to each follow their own path.

Long shot I know, but had to ask. Book used to be at my parents house but now it is MIA.